# Discord.js - Sort role by alphabetical

Tags: discord.js

need help with something.

```js
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'mods')) {
            var members = {};
        message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
            if (member.roles.find(r => r.name === "⭐｜Administrator") || member.roles.find(r => r.name === "⭐｜Discord Moderator")) {
                if (!members[member.hoistRole ? member.hoistRole.name : 'None']) {
                    members[member.hoistRole ? member.hoistRole.name : 'None'] = [];
                }
                members[member.hoistRole ? member.hoistRole.name : 'None'].push(member);
            }
        });

        var mods = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('Game Administrators')
            .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL)
            .setFooter('Game Administrators', client.user.iconURL)
            .setColor(message.guild.me.displayColor)
            .setTimestamp();

        for (var role in members) {
            var str = '';
            var arr = members[role];

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var user = arr[i].user;
                if (user.presence.status === 'offline') {
                    str += '<:offline:496919419298119692> **' + arr[i].displayName + '**\n';
                } else if (user.presence.status === 'idle') {
                    str += '<:idle:496919399257604115> **' + arr[i].displayName + '**\n';
                } else if (user.presence.status === 'online') {
                    str += '<:online:496919410058199042> **' + arr[i].displayName + '**\n';
                } else if (user.presence.status === 'dnd') {
                    str += '<:dnd:496919391376506880> **' + arr[i].displayName + '**\n';
                }
            }

            arr = members[role];
            mods.addField(role, str);
        }

        message.channel.send({ embed: mods });
    }
```

We have the first role Admin and the second Moderator, but the command is showing the moderator first and then Admin. What is the best way to do, that appear in role order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

Example:

```js
// V12
message.channel.send(message.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.name).sort().join(", "))
```

```js
// V11
message.channel.send(message.guild.roles.map(role => role.name).sort().join(", "))
```